# Bifurcate Records respective to months

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, monthcalendar

Here, I am going to explain my scenario:

I have following tables:

```
Table : Service_Type

Id  | Service_Name | Service_Table_Name|
----------------------------------------
1   |   FA         |    FA     |
2   |   TPA        |        TPA        |


Table: Service_Mapping

Id  | Service_Type_Id |
---------------------------
1   |   1     |
2   |   2     |
3   |   2     |
4   |   1     |

Table: FA

Id  | Created_date| Qty |
-----------------------------
1   | 3/20/2012   | 20  |
2   | 4/22/2012   | 10  |
3   | 5/12/2012   | 15  |
4   | 6/3/2012    | 5   |

Table: TPA

Id  | Created_date| Qty |
-----------------------------
1   | 5/20/2012   | 2   |
2   | 7/22/2012   | 10  |
3   | 1/12/2012   | 1   |
4   | 9/3/2012    | 5   |
```

I want output like this :

```
Month | FA| TPA|
----------------
Jan     0   1
Mar     1   0
Apr     1   0
Jul     1   0
Sep     0   1
```

In output I want month respective to Created_date field of FA and TPA Table. And Respective to Month I want total sum how many FA and TPA occurs in a month.

I have get output like

```
FA   |  TPA  |
--------------
3    |  2    |

SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN Service_Type_Id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FA, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Service_Type_Id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TPA 
FROM Service_Mapping
```

But Now I want to bifurcate them respective to months they occurs. From Date filed of TPA and FA.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Mon.monthNAME, ISNULL(TPAcount,0) TPAcount, ISNULL(FAcount,0) FAcount FROM
(
    SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,created_date) AS [monthNAME], MONTH(created_date) [month], YEAR(created_date) as [year] FROM FA
    UNION
    SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,created_date) AS [monthNAME], MONTH(created_date) [month], YEAR(created_date) as [year]  FROM TPA
) Mon LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,created_date) tpaMonth, YEAR(created_date) as [year] , COUNT(1) TPAcount 
    FROM TPA GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,created_date), YEAR(created_date)
) TPA ON TPA.tpaMonth = Mon.monthNAME and tpa.[year] = mon.[year] LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,created_date) faMonth, YEAR(created_date) as [year] , COUNT(1) FAcount 
    FROM FA GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,created_date), YEAR(created_date)
) FA ON FA.faMonth = MON.monthNAME and FA.[year] = mon.[year]

ORDER BY 
 Mon.[year], Mon.[month]
```

Comment: I don't know why it is showing me this error message .......  Error Message: ‘Mon.month’ is not a recognized datename option.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work at your site. I created the same tables as you have at it works fine for me. Have you tried my both queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can check also another approach:

```
SELECT Mon.monthNAME, SUM(tpCount) tpCount, SUM(faCount) faCount FROM
(
    SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,created_date) AS [monthNAME], MONTH(created_date) [month], YEAR(created_date) as [year], 0 AS tpCount, 1 as faCount FROM FA
    UNION
    SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,created_date) AS [monthNAME], MONTH(created_date) [month], YEAR(created_date) as [year], 1 as tpCount, 0 AS faCount FROM TPA
) Mon 
GROUP BY 
   [monthNAME],[month],[year]
ORDER BY 
    Mon.[year], Mon.[month]
```

Comment: This query works fine. But Now If I add more Services eg. FA,TPA,Gift,AA etc.. Then What change I have to do in this ?

Comment: You'll have to add next unions and add new columns to the current selects. For example if you want to add GIFT table, you'll have to add 0 as GiftCount in current selects and then next union as follows: SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,created_date) AS [monthNAME], MONTH(created_date) [month], YEAR(created_date) as [year], 0 as tpCount, 0 AS faCount, 1 as GiftCount FROM Gift